# Vapor Swift - Compare two strings

Tags: vapor, leaf

I would like to compare a variable with a string in my leaf template.

I get the variable through the controller in my template:

```html
<!-- NAVBAR -->
<!-- #(path) = /database -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            #if(path == "/database") {
                <h1>Hello, there!</h1>
            }
            <li><a href="#">Filldatabase</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- END NAVBAR -->
```

I want it so that when I am on the `/database` page, I get an h1 that says "Hello, there!". How can I do it? I think I need to use `#if()`, but I can't find the proper syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `#equal()` tag. You pass in two parameters, and if they are the same, if includes the HTML in the braces:

```
#equal("hello", "hello") {
    <!-- This is shown -->
    <p>Equal</p>
}
#equal("hello", "world") {
     <!-- This is not shown -->
     <p>Not Equal</p>
}
```

So what you wan to use is this:

```
#equal(path, "/database") {
    <h1>Hello, there!</h1>
}
```